# How to convert this nested json to angular material table

Tags: json, angular8

https://www.chefx.in:4000/api/r/methoddetails

This link contains the josn data please let me know to get it into table im learning angular basics

Answer (score 0):

Link is not opening use `JSON.Parse` and assign it to data table.

You can check this.

```
let a = data (Your JSON Data)
let b = JSON.parse(a);
[dataSource]="b"   // assigning data to the table in angular material
```